# dd outputting: "function not implemented" when trying to write to /dev/sg11

Tags: devices, dd, scsi

I'm trying to use the following command:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sg11 bs=16K count=1
```

But when executing it, I get the following error:

```
dd: writing `/dev/sg11': Function not implemented
```

When I try with `dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sg11 bs=16K count=1 conv=fsync`, then I get a `cannot allocate memory` error, which becomes a `Function not implemented` error when I up the bs size.

What causes this issue and how can I fix it?

UPDATE: Sometimes it will tell me `cannot allocate memory`, and then it will again tell me that `function not implemented` for the same bs value.

Comment: Note that `bs` and `count` together just specify *how much data to copy*. The real data comes from `if`, which you specify as /dev/urandom -- that is, random data.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I was aware of that from the `man` pages :P I was using different values of bs in order to see if it was a sector/block write size issue, which it ended up not being.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`/dev/sgxx` is a SCSI-generic device, which allows sending and receiving of raw SCSI commands. When you write to the device, you are expected to start the write with a SCSI header, which defines the operation you wish to do.

Writing random data to an `sg` device is really a bad idea. You'll be sending random SCSI commands, which might not even exist (hence `function not implemented`) and furthermore giving a random byte length for the operation, which is highly likely to result in `cannot allocate memory`. (If you're really unlucky, the random command might do something.)

Depending on what device you actually have connected to `/dev/sg11`, you might want to investigate the `sg3_utils` package, or some more specific SCSI device driver like `st` (tape drives).

One of the useful utility commands which comes with the sg utils is `sg_map`, which can let you know what the primary device corresponding to an sg device. On non-ancient Linux systems, you can also install `lsscsi` which provides a nice listing of SCSI devices, again with both the /dev/sg device and the primary device.

sg3_utils also includes `sg_dd` which is a version of `dd` which understands the low-level SCSI protocol. (But only use it if you know what you're doing!)

Comment: Right. I got that clarified with a coworker. I had to grep and awk with sg_map to get the block device I could actually write to. I guess you can edit your answer to incorporate that and I will accept, or I'll post that solution myself!

Comment: @ardentsonata: done, I think.

Comment: This is worth an upvote just for "if you're really unlucky, the random command might do something", IMO.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling, I agree with that sentiment.